# Software Version Control

Tags: svn, version-control

(I think this is on topic...feel free to correct me if it isn't).

I have a program. Used internally to project management and timesheeting.
Another of our other offices wants to use said program too.
Their requirements vary in places though.

So, now what do I do?
I initially thought to just have two separate programs. Obviously though, this makes it hard to apply bug fixes to both.
A second thought was to branch the program into two branches. Any differing code should be removed from the trunk and maintained only in the branches. This way bug fixes and the like could be applied at the trunk level and then "propagate" through to the branches.

The requirements are varying enough that handling them in the code base would make things very messy and unmaintainable, plus this has the potential to be used for even more offices, which would then result in further branches (if I took that path).

Is there any suggestions on the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: Sorry - there's no real right answer to this. What you do will be governed by by your specific circumstances. Any opinions voice will be exactly that, and questions attracting primarily opinion-based answers are off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your design.

It the programs are very similar (only differ by options, branding, etc.) then you should abstract out the differences into config files, plug-ins etc.

If the programs are only somewhat similar, you should move all common functionality to libraries or base classes.

The main idea is factoring out common code, and maintaining that in *one* place. The rest of the code should be maintained separately.

Comment: Yeah, so similar to the branching idea. Just at a higher level. I suspected that might be the way to go. The design is unfortunate; it's one of those situations where someone's seen it and gone "oh, that's useful, we should have that too" rather than something that could have been pre-planned/designed better. So pulling stuff out is probably going to be a major undertaking :(

Comment: Unfortunately that's probably a question that's a bit to big to get much assistance from here.  Perhaps if you provide more specific details (language, framework/platform, overall design, etc.) we could be of more help.  Most languages (even something crappy like VB6) should allow you to at least pull out large pieces into re-usable modules.

Comment: You can start today! Even if it's just dumb "utils" functions. You can start *somewhere* and slowly move pieces to the "common" repository as you factor them out of the branches.  I think this would be an applicable place to use SVN externals (pointing to the common repo).

Comment: Yeah, all good. The refactoring is do-able, it's just going suck given the size of the project and all. Thanks for your thoughts on the matter :)

Comment: I understand all too well :-) Just think of it as a math factoring problem!